# ¿Comó obtener el contenido de una fila de un QTableWidget Python PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

He estado tratando de obtener el contenido de una fila de un QTableWidget, pero cuando lo intento me sale el siguiente error: Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "prueba.pyw", line 24, in guardar_datos
    nombre = self.table.item(row, 0).text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

```
nombre = self.table.item(0, 0).text()
        apellido = self.table.item(0, 1).text()
        edad = self.table.item(0, 2).text()
        cursor = conexion.cursor()
        sql = ("INSERT INTO DATOS (NOMBRE, APELLIDO, EDAD) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)")
        valores = (nombre, apellido, edad)
        cursor.execute(sql, valores)
        conexion.commit()
        conexion.close()
```

Alguien me podría decir otro método para hacerlo, o si estoy haciendo algo mal, gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Hola Josue, en el código que aportas no agregas la linea de código que causa el error, pero el método `item` **retorna `None` si el item no existe**, de ahí el error (`None` no tiene el atributo `text` como es lógico). Esto significa que tu fila (`row`) no es un índice válido para la tabla, no existe esa fila o no tiene asignado ningún item. Para poder saber la causa habría que saber de dónde viene `row` y cómo construyes la tabla o el tamaño que tiene. Un saludo.

Comment: Saludos FJSevilla, Gracias por dedicar un poco de su tiempo para responderme, (row) es una variable que asigné para ir recorriendo todas las filas, y se incrementa mediante un bucle que creé, en teoría ese sería el index de las filas. La tabla la creé con el Qt Disigner, ésta tiene 3 columnas y 3 filas. Muy buena información seguiré intentando con esa información que me brindó, veré si lo puedo solucionar. Gracias nuevamente!

Comment: He agregado una imagen para que sea más expresivo lo que quiero decir.

Answer (score 1):

La imagen no se ve.
El problema es que tienes celdas vacías, o que estás tratando de leer las coordenadas erroneas. Para evitar seleccionar una fila que no exista, te sugiero que utilices un método de selección.

Una manera de lograrlo sería permitir a la tabla la selección de una sola fila y ejecutar un código que se active al clickear en cualquier celda de esa fila.

```
table.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
table.cellClicked.connect(funcionalclickearceldas)

def funcionalclickearceldas():
    nombre = table.selectedIndexes()[0].data()
    apellido = table.selectedIndexes()[1].data()
    edad = table.selectedIndexes()[2].data()
    print(f"has clickeado en {nombre} {apellido} y tiene {edad} años")
```

Comment: ¿Has testeado tu solución?

Comment: Sí. Es la que utilizo desde hace meses en mi ERP (multitud de tablas) sin problemas. La versión que utilizo es 5.13

Comment: Es que me parece extraño ya que `table.selectedIndexes()` es una lista de QModelIndex por lo que `table.selectedIndexes()[0]` es un QModelIndex, y su metodo `data()` sin parámetros retorna el valor asociado al role Qt::DisplayRole en el QModelIndex que es un string, hasta ese punto todo correcto, pero lo que me parece extraño es que la linea: `nombre, apellido, edad = record` no te genere un error ya que como señale record es un string(salvo que hayas modificado algo en el modelo). Podrias proveer un MWE para poder testearlo :-)

Comment: Tienes razón. Al copiarlo a stackoverflow confundí un par de lineas y cambié lo que no debía.

Answer (score 1):

No toda cuadricula de un QTableWidget tiene asociado un QTableWidgetItem, asi que cuando obtengas la informacion verifica que el item no sea None, y en el caso de Qt Designer solo los items que has modificado tienen un QTableWidgetItem.

```py
row = 0
cols = (0, 1, 2)

valores = []
for col in cols:
    it = self.table.item(row, col)
    if it is None:
        it = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.table.setItem(row, col, it)
    valores.append(it.text())
cursor = conexion.cursor()
sql = ("INSERT INTO DATOS (NOMBRE, APELLIDO, EDAD) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)")
cursor.execute(sql, valores)
conexion.commit()
```

Otra solución es usar los QModelIndex ya que en este caso toda cuadricula si tiene asociado uno:

```py
row = 0
cols = (0, 1, 2)

valores = []
for col in cols:
    ix = self.table.model().index(row, col)
    valores.append(ix.data())
cursor = conexion.cursor()
sql = ("INSERT INTO DATOS (NOMBRE, APELLIDO, EDAD) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)")
cursor.execute(sql, valores)
conexion.commit()
```